# React hooks - cannot type in input field [NOT duplicate]

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

You can check the full code here:
[CODESANDBOX LINK](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-leftpad-27woh?file=/src/App.js)

This is really weird. 
I have a list of input fields which are rendered dynamically depending on the button click

```
const newFields = (index) =>
<div>
    <input value={inputs[index].name}  onChange={e => handleNameInput(e,index)} />
    <input value={inputs[index].age} type="number" onChange={e => handleAgeInput(e,index)} />
    <Button onClick={() => setInputArray(inputArray => [...inputArray, newFields(++index)])}>Add</Button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to store the values of the inputs and update them onChange. But as stated in the title, I can't type in the input field and once I click a character the input loses focus. I don't know why is that happening.

Here are the states and the handleInput function:

```
  let [inputs, setInputs] = useState(Array.apply(null, Array(100)).map(function () { return {
    name: '',
    age: ''
  } }));

const handleNameInput = (e, i) =>{
  let tempArr = new Array();
  tempArr = [...inputs];
  tempArr[i].name = e.target.value;
  setInputs([...tempArr]);
}

//handleAgeInput is exactly the same
```

Comment: There is some issue in the closures, that's for sure, but I'm not understanding how you are using `inputArray` and `input`. Can you explain me? Because, as far as I've understood, in `inputArray` you are saving the HTML elements, while in `input` you are just saving the values.. Correct? Is this mandatory? Because I'm pretty sure you can achieve what you want just with the `input` array. I can provie you an example

Comment: I'm using input array to display the fields dynamically, at the beginning the page display one set of input fields. Then if you click the button it will add new set of input fields. What I want to do is to store the values in each input field in the inputs array

Comment: please check the sandbox link to see the app, Its very easy to understand the issue then
https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-leftpad-27woh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I did look at the sandbox, and did understand what you wanted to achieve, but I was wondering if some of your implementation choices were made on purpose or not, because there are simpler way to obtain your needs. For example, like in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Jolly Well, I tried to simplify the program here and mention the only relevant parts, but my actual program is a bit complicated. That's why you might find easier ways to achieve same things. But the only thing I want to understand is why I couldn't type in the fields. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main issue is the duplicate usage of arrays. The facts is, you want only one array of datas. So, you need to build your component around it. If you make another array on state, you're adding complexity and it's resulting to you're current issue.

### Understand why there is no updates

You're `onChange` function call update the `inputs` array state. BUT, you're rendering the `inputArray` where nothing change to him. No `setInputArray` call so, no re-render.

### Proposal

There is proposal implementation of what I understand of you needs :

```
function App() {
  let [inputArray, setInputArray] = useState([{
    name: "",
    age: ""
  }]);

  const handleNameInput = useCallback(
    (e, i) => {
      inputArray[i].name = e.target.value;
      setInputArray([...inputArray]);
    },
    [inputArray]
  );

  const handleAgeInput = useCallback(
    (e, i) => {
      inputArray[i].age = e.target.value;
      setInputArray([...inputArray]);
    },
    [inputArray]
  );

  const handleNewField = useCallback(() =>
    setInputArray(inputArray => [...inputArray, {
      name: "",
      age: ""
    }]),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {inputArray.map((element, i) => (
        <div>
          <input
            value={element.name}
            onChange={e => handleNameInput(e, i)}
          />
          <input
            value={element.age}
            type="number"
            onChange={e => handleAgeInput(e, i)}
          />
          <button
            onClick={handleNewField}>
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Depending of you needs maybe you should adapt it. There is some ways to avoid re-render the whole list. But this way you can edit all fields

One another proper way to do this is to to make each fields group as another Component.with independents states.

If you want the button juste once, move him from the loop.

If you want to display only the last fields set, take the `inputArrays[inputArray.length]` instead of loop on all.

### Explanation :

You're rendering an array of components `{ inputArray.map((e, i) => { return <div key={i}> {e} </div>; })}` where `e` should be a component.

In another hand, you're maintaining an array of datas that's "shadowing" the first array.

The main concept of your use case as far I can understand, should be to render your components directly from your datas – your array of datas.
This way you have only one source of truth.

Comment: Can you give me a short explanation on what was my mistake exactly? The code worked by the way so thanks.

Comment: I just edit the top of my answer if it's enough for you. If I miss something don't hesitate to ask me :) . I saw many mistakes in your code so, I don't know if it's a simplification of a more complicated component. Or, if you don't have some knowledge (which is obvious if you ask questions anyways xD)

Comment: Well actually its part of a more complicated program but I tried to simplify it here to be easy for everyone to solve. So I needed both arrays actually but I will modify my code accordingly, the only thing I need to understand is why I couldn't type in the fields?

Comment: Ok so I'll add another explanation to answer this exact question :)

Comment: TL;DR : `setInputArray` so `inputArray` has no changes so there is no re-render of your builded `newFields` component. That's mainly why my core answer is around to avoid this two states.